# How to use identical C types from different packages?

Tags: go, cgo

I'm trying to use cairo bindings (Go package), which defines a wrapper structure with a C type in it, with a C function, but can't make it work.

The cairo package defines a Context:

```
package cairo
...
type Context struct {
    Ptr *C.cairo_t
}
...
```

Then, from the main package, I want to use its pointer:

```
package main
...
cr := cairo.Create(surf.Surface)
layout := C.pango_cairo_create_layout(cr.Ptr)
...
```

The `C.pango_cairo_create_layout` accepts `*C.cairo_t`, which is what `cr.Ptr` should be. However, the go compiler doesn't agree:

```
./main.go:114:157: cannot use cr.Ptr (type *cairo._Ctype_struct__cairo) as type *_Ctype_struct__cairo in argument to func literal
```

As can be seen, `cr.Ptr` is of type `*cairo.C.cairo_t` and not `*C.cairo_t`, that is, the package namespace is a part of the type.

I've found https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13467, which talks about a workaround using the combination of the reflect package and `unsafe.Pointer`. However, I can't make it work.

How do I correctly "bend" this so it compiles **and** works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested, I've figured it out.

```
package main
...
cr := cairo.Create(surf.Surface)
ptr := (*C.cairo_t)(unsafe.Pointer(reflect.ValueOf(cr.Ptr).Pointer()))
layout := C.pango_cairo_create_layout(ptr)
...
```

Maybe it can be done more simply, but this works.